# Change background colour of Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an Android project and included **Navigation Drawer Activity**.

[image]

But the backgrounds of the activities are black.

[image]

I know I can change the background colour to white using XML or Java. But every time I do that I need to change other views as well. I checked the styles file. But it doesn't contain any tag about the background colour.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Is there any solution for that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your app Theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

Answer (score 0):

you can Extend your app Theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light or you can pass background color to the root view of you activity layout.